# Unable to refresh access token error in blackberry facebook integration

Tags: blackberry

I found [facebook-bb-sdk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/)

When I run the code it shows 
`Unable to refresh access token error.`

Why is this happening?

Comment: This question is pretty vague. You may want to add some of your code or something.

Answer (score 0):

Hi koti until today 8 Jun 2011 something has changed on the FB login page, read this::

> http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Facebook-SDK-problems/td-p/730881

so don´t use it for now, and hope it will be fixed soon!!!

instead you can use the sharer.php file loading into a BrowserField

for example::

> http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=htttp://www.google.com&t=sharing
>   this link